# theano (python): elementwise gradient

Tags: python, theano, elementwise-operations

I'm trying to perform elementwise gradient with

e.g.,

output-f(x): 5 by 1 vector,

with respect to 
input-X: 5 by 1 vector

I can do this like,

```
 import theano
 import theano.tensor as T

 X = T.vector('X')   

 f = X*3    

 [rfrx, []] = theano.scan(lambda j, f,X : T.grad(f[j], X), sequences=T.arange(X.shape[0]), non_sequences=[f,X])

 fcn_rfrx = theano.function([X], rfrx)

 fcn_rfrx(np.ones(5,).astype(float32))
```

and the result is

```
array([[ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.]], dtype=float32)
```

but since it's not efficient, i want to get 5 by 1 vector as a result

by doing something like..

```
 [rfrx, []] = theano.scan(lambda j, f,X : T.grad(f[j], X[j]), sequences=T.arange(X.shape[0]), non_sequences=[f,X])
```

which doesn't work.

Is there any way of do this?
(sorry for bad format..I'm new here and learning)

---

(I added more clear example):

given input vector: x[1], x[2], ..., x[n]

and output vector: y[1], y[2], .., y[n],

where y[i] = f(x[i]).

I want the result of

df(x[i])/dx[i] only

and not the

df(x[i])/dx[j] for (i<>j)

, for computational efficiency (n is number of data > 10000)

Comment: can you just sum the output: `f.sum()` and take the gradient w.r.t. X?

Comment: @Alleo I added an example for not confusing. Is that mean theano will automatically not try df(x[i])/dx[j] for (i<>j)?

Comment: given your additional formulation (`y[i] = f(x[i])`), there are no problems in taking sum and then computing gradient. Theano should reduce unnecessary computations.

Comment: OK, I've checked it works in acceptable speed for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `theano.tensor.jacobian`.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.fvector()
p = T.as_tensor_variable([(x ** i).sum() for i in range(5)])

j = T.jacobian(p, x)

f = theano.function([x], [p, j])
```

Now evaluating yields

```
In [31]: f([1., 2., 3.])
Out[31]: 
[array([  3.,   6.,  14.,  36.,  98.], dtype=float32),
 array([[   0.,    0.,    0.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   2.,    4.,    6.],
        [   3.,   12.,   27.],
        [   4.,   32.,  108.]], dtype=float32)]
```

If you are interested in only one, or a few partial derivatives, you can obtain only them also. It would be necessary to take a close look at the theano optimization rules to be able to see how much more efficient this gets (a benchmark is a first test). (It is possible that already indexing into the gradient makes it clear to theano that it does not need to calculate the rest).

```
x = T.fscalar()
y = T.fvector()
z = T.concatenate([x.reshape((1,)), y.reshape((-1,))])

e = (z ** 2).sum()
g = T.grad(e, wrt=x)

ff = theano.function([x, y], [e, g])
```

Comment: I guess my question was confusing, I added one more example. My point is, I don't want to perform gradient w.r.t unneeded elements, with same vector size of input and output.

Comment: So, is that mean theano will automatically and efficiently not try df(x[i])/dx[j] for (i<>j) when we use like 'f.sum()'?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this go in the direction of your question?

Comment: Yes it does, I've checked that using this way ('f.sum()') works acceptably fast for my case, without closer look.